# How to calculate this definite integral $\int_0^1\frac{{\ln^4 x }}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{5\pi^5}{64}$

Tags: integration

$$\displaystyle\int_0^1\dfrac{{\ln^4 x}}{1+x^2}\text{d}x=\dfrac{5\pi^5}{64}$$

let $x=e^{-t}$，
$$
\displaystyle\int_0^1\dfrac{({\ln x})^4}{1+x^2}\text{d}x=\displaystyle\int_0^{+\infty}\dfrac{t^4\text{e}^{-t}}{1+\text{e}^{-2t}}\text{d}t=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\displaystyle\int_0^{+\infty}t^4\text{e}^{-(2k+1)t}\text{d}t. 
$$
let $u=(2k+1)t$，
$$
\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\displaystyle\int_0^{+\infty}t^4\text{e}^{-(2k+1)t}\text{d}t=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^5}\Gamma(5)=24\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^5}. 
$$
I don't know how to solve this series.

So how can I solve this series? And is there any other ways to solve this definite integral. Thank you.

Comment: It is $$\frac{\zeta \left(5,\frac{1}{4}\right)-\zeta
   \left(5,\frac{3}{4}\right)}{1024}$$

Comment: $\ln (x^4)$ or $(\ln x)^4$?

Comment: $\left(\ln x\right)^4$，sorry，I've re-edited it.

Comment: See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function#Special_values

Comment: Maple gives for the indefinite integral the following answer: $ \left( 3/4\,{\it LerchPhi} \left( -{x}^{2},5,1/2 \right) +3/2\,
 \left( \ln  \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}{\it LerchPhi} \left( -{x}^
{2},3,1/2 \right) -3/2\,\ln  \left( x \right) {\it LerchPhi} \left( -{
x}^{2},4,1/2 \right) - \left( \ln  \left( x \right)  \right) ^{3}{\it 
LerchPhi} \left( -{x}^{2},2,1/2 \right) +1/2\, \left( \ln  \left( x
 \right)  \right) ^{4}{\it LerchPhi} \left( -{x}^{2},1,1/2 \right) 
 \right) x
$

Comment: @SHZ I think you meant $$\frac{5\pi^5}{64}$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd like to add a sel-contained answer. We may consider that
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n} $$
is the $2\pi$-periodic extension of a linear function, which equals $\frac{\pi-x}{2}$ on $(0,2\pi)$. The convergence is uniform over any compact subset of $\mathbb{R}\setminus 2\pi\mathbb{Z}$. If we integrate both sides four times, we get that
$$ g(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n^5} $$
is the $2\pi$-periodic extension of a polynomial with degree five, $p(x)=-\frac{x^5}{240}+\frac{\pi  x^4}{48}-\frac{\pi ^2 x^3}{36}+\frac{\pi ^4 x}{90}$.
 The convergence is uniform over $\mathbb{R}$, hence by evaluating $g$ and $p$ at $\pi/2$ we get
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin(n\pi/2)}{n^5} = \sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^5} = p\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\frac{5\pi^5}{1536}.$$
Not by chance, this is related to the value of the wanted integral. By termwise integration

$$ \int_{0}^{1}\log^4(x)\sum_{k\geq 0}(-1)^k x^{2k}\,dx = \sum_{k\geq 0}(-1)^k\int_{0}^{1}x^{2k}\log^4(x)\,dx =\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{24(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^5}$$
so
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log^4(x)\,dx}{1+x^2} = 24 p\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\color{red}{\frac{5\pi^5}{64}}.$$
Summarizing, it is enough to exploit the Fourier series of [Bernoulli polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials).

---

As an alternative, we may use Feynman's trick. By Euler's Beta function and the reflection formula for the $\Gamma$ function we have that 
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^s\,dx}{1+x^2} = \frac{\pi}{2}\sec\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)$$
holds for any $s\in(-1,1)$. If we differentiate (with respect to $s$) both sides four times, then perform an evaluation at $s=0$, we get
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log^4(x)\,dx}{1+x^2}=\frac{3\pi^5}{8}\cdot[z^4]\sec(z)=\frac{3\pi^5}{8}\cdot[z^4]\frac{1}{1-\frac{z^2}{2}+\frac{z^4}{24}}=\frac{3\pi^5}{8}\left(\frac{1}{2^2}-\frac{1}{24}\right) $$
and the conclusion is just the same.

Answer (score 5):

Your approach works perfectly fine! What you have there, in the last line, is the so-called [Dirichlet Beta Function $\beta(s)$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletBetaFunction.html). What you are looking for in particular is the value of $\beta(5)$ which is in fact expressable in terms of $\pi^5$ yet alone (as linked by *Zacky*). Similiar to the Riemann Zeta Function, where we have a formula for $\zeta(2n)$, there is a formula for computing $\beta(2n+1)$ for $n\in\Bbb N_0$. In order to be precise we have that

> $$\beta(2n+1)~=~(-1)^n\frac{\pi^{2n+1}}{4^{n+1}(2n)!}\operatorname{E}_{2n}\tag1$$

Here $E_n$ denotes a [Euler Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_number). Using $(1)$ you will obtain the value you are looking for. To give some more context. *Dr. Sonnhard Graubner* gave the value in terms of the Hurwitz Zeta Function $\zeta(s,a)$, which has a quite simple relation to the Dirichlet Beta Function (similiar with the mentioned Lerch Transcendent). *Allawonder* essentially gave you the integral representation of $\beta(s)$.

Currently I am not aware of a simpler derivation, not relying on $(1)$. However, as with $\beta(3)$ there might exist an elementary way of evaluating the integral or the sum, respectively.

Comment: Well, the fact that the values of $\beta$ over the odd integers are related to the Maclaurin coefficients of $\frac{1}{\cos}$ can be proved by Feynman's trick or Bernoulli polynomials.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the indefinite $$\int\frac{t^4e^{-t}}{1+e^{-2t}}\mathrm d t,$$ put this into the form $$\frac12\int\frac{2t^4}{e^t+e^{-t}}\mathrm d t=\frac12\int\frac{t^4}{\cosh t}\mathrm d t.$$ If we integrate by parts, this will definitely reduce the problem since the $$\int\frac{1}{\cosh t}\mathrm d t$$ may be easily done, for example by substituting $x=\tanh(t/2),$ or here since you'll eventually compute with it, write $1/\cosh t$ as $$\frac{2e^t}{1+(e^t)^2}.$$

Comment: Have you tried to integrate it by parts?

Comment: @Zacky Integrating once by parts reduces the problem to evaluating the $$\int_0^{\infty}{t^3\arctan(e^t)\mathrm d t}.$$

Comment: Yes. Sorry, but I don't think integrating by parts help here.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
J&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^4 x}{1+x^2}\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^4 x}{1+x^2}\,dx\\
J_n&=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^{2n} x}{1+x^2}\,dx\\
J&=\frac{1}{2}J_2\\
K_n&=\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^{2n}(xy)}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}\,dx\,dy\\
&\overset{u=yx}=\int_0^\infty\left(\int_0^\infty\frac{y\ln^{2n} u}{(u^2+y^2)(1+y^2)}\,du\right)\,dy\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty\left[\ln\left(\frac{u^2+y^2}{1+y^2}\right)\right]_{y=0}^{y=\infty}\frac{\ln^{2n} u}{1-u^2}\,du\\
&=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^{2n+1}u}{u^2-1}\,du\\
&=2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^{2n+1}u}{u^2-1}\,du\\
&=2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^{2n+1}u}{u-1}\,du-2\int_0^1 \frac{u\ln^{2n+1}u}{u^2-1}\,du\\
&=\left(2-\frac{1}{2^{2n+1}}\right)\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^{2n+1}u}{u-1}\,du\\
&=(2n+1)!\left(2-\frac{1}{2^{2n+1}}\right)\zeta(2n+2)
\end{align}On the other hand,
\begin{align}
K_1&=2\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2 x}{1+x^2}\,dx\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+y^2}\,dy\\
&=\pi J_1\\
K_2&=6J_1^2+\pi J_2\\
&=\frac{6K_1^2}{\pi^2}+\pi J_2\\
J_2&=\frac{K_2}{\pi}-\frac{6K_1^2}{\pi^3}\\
&=\frac{945\zeta(6)}{4\pi}-\frac{6075\zeta^2(4)}{8\pi^3}\\
\end{align}Moreover,\begin{align}\zeta(4)&=\frac{\pi^4}{90}\\
\zeta(6)&=\frac{\pi^6}{945}
\end{align}Therefore,\begin{align}\boxed{J=\frac{5}{64}\pi^5}\end{align}

NB: for $n\geq 0$ integer \begin{align}\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^{2n+1} x}{1+x^2}\,dx=0\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[#ffd,15px]{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{4}\pars{x} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x =
{5\pi^{5} \over 64}}:\ {\large ?}}$

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{4}\pars{x} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x & =
\left.\partiald[4]{}{\mu}\int_{0}^{1}{x^{\mu} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x
\,\right\vert_{\ \mu\ =\ 0} =
\left.\partiald[4]{}{\mu}\int_{0}^{1}{x^{\mu} - x^{\mu + 2} \over
1 - x^{4}}\,\dd x\,\right\vert_{\ \mu\ =\ 0}
\\[5mm] & \stackrel{x^{\large 4}\ \mapsto\ x}{=}\,\,\,
\left.{1 \over 4}\,\partiald[4]{}{\mu}\int_{0}^{1}{x^{\mu/4 - 3/4} -
x^{\mu/4 - 1/4} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x\,\right\vert_{\ \mu\ =\ 0}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 4}\,\partiald[4]{}{\mu}\bracks{%
\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{\mu/4 - 1/4} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x -
\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{\mu/4 - 3/4} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x}_{\ \mu\ =\ 0}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 4}\,\partiald[4]{}{\mu}\bracks{%
\Psi\pars{{\mu \over 4} + {3 \over 4}} -
\Psi\pars{{\mu \over 4} + {1 \over 4}}}_{\ \mu\ =\ 0}\label{1}\tag{1}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 4}\,{1 \over 4^{4}}\bracks{%
\Psi^{\pars{\tt IV}}\pars{3 \over 4} - \Psi^{\pars{\tt IV}}\pars{1 \over 4}}
\\[5mm] & =
\left.{1 \over 1024}\,\totald[4]{\bracks{\pi\cot\pars{\pi z}}}{z}
\,\right\vert_{\ z\ =\ 1/4}\label{2}\tag{2}
\\[5mm] & =
\left.{8\pi^{5}\cot\pars{\pi z}\csc^{2}\pars{\pi z}
\bracks{\cot^{2}\pars{\pi z} + 2\csc^{2}\pars{\pi z}} \over 1024}
\right\vert_{\ z\ =\ 1/4}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbox[15px,#ffd,border:1px solid navy]{5\pi^{5} \over 64}\
\approx\ 23.9078
\end{align}

$\ds{\Psi}$ is the [Digamma Function](http://people.math.sfu.ca/%7Ecbm/aands/page_258.htm).

\ref{1}: See [${\bf\color{black}{6.3.22}}$ in this link](http://people.math.sfu.ca/%7Ecbm/aands/page_259.htm).

\ref{2}: [Euler Reflection Formula ${\bf\color{black}{6.3.7}}$](http://people.math.sfu.ca/%7Ecbm/aands/page_259.htm)